# is there a way to keep a session alive even when logging out?

Tags: login, session

While I am always logging into a CentOS server for simulations it got me thinking:

why can't I keep running the simulations even if my session is closed?

I know that when a session is ended or a user logs out,

any process generated from the session is also terminated.

Could there be a way to let the processes keep on running by itself

even if the session is closed?

-- a silly question from a user with not much unix background :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at `screen` or, even better, `tmux`.

These allow you to do exactly what you want. `tmux` also allows you to split the session into multiple windows.

Comment: thanks! I'm looking at screen and it looks nice already!

Answer (score 4):

Sure there is! tmux and screen are both classic solution as well as nohup.

Comment: You should accept garethTheReds answer, it'll mark the question as solved for others to find and he beat me too it. : )